# Checkbox self-unchecks if label has span inside

Tags: html, css

This works as expected:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    checkbox
</label>
```

However when I put text inside `span` checkbox unchecks by itself when clicked:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>checkbox</span>
</label>
```

I found out setting `pointer-events: none` for `span` solves this problem. 
However could someone explain why this happens? And is there any better solution?

## Edit

**I see this problem only from my localhost using CodeKit. It works fine when I open my .html file directly**

Comment: Feel free to delete your question, since it doesn't appear to be reproducible here.

Comment: It says my question can't be deleted. Maybe it's good. Maybe someone will have the same problem as me and this question will help them

Comment: If you want that, please add an answer with what exactly the "CodeKit bug" is so that it will in fact help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I am not having any problems. Can you try it in another browser?

[image: HTML Code]

[image: Browser output]